# How to deal with changes when adding new field to a data class in Kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin, pseudocode, data-class

I had this data class:

```
data class User(
  val name:String,
  val age: Int
)
```

I save users' data with this in my database, and now the problem is I want to add a new field

```
val gender: String
```

and if I added this the app crashed when retrieving users' data from the database because it is not the same data any more.

This is my code to retrieve data from the database:

```
@Query("SELECT*FROM users WHERE name =:name")
suspend fun getUser(name:String):Flow<User>
```

I would be most interested in seeing a pseudocode solution if possible.

Comment: If it's Room then read about migrations (easy to find with internet search) ... also if geneder is nullable in database you property also should be nullable

Comment: The solution is just to migrate? Okay I can try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a migration of your database. You can find all the instructions to do it there [Migrating Room databases](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions).

**If your room version is 2.4.0-alpha01 or higher:**

Replace in your database:

```
@Database(
  version = 1,
  entities = {User.class}
)
```

with:

```
@Database(
  version = 2,
  entities = {User.class},
  autoMigrations = {
    @AutoMigration (from = 1, to = 2)
  }
)
```

**Else you will need to du the migration manually:**

Add this to your Database class:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
  @Override
  public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users "
      + " ADD COLUMN gender TEXT");
  }
};
```

and add `.addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)` to your `Room.databaseBuilder()`

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions, the right one and the fast one:

The right one:

```
@Database(
     version = 2,
     entities = [User::class],
     autoMigrations = [
         AutoMigration (from = 1, to = 2)
     ]
)
```

Code taken from: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#automated

This is a migration , since in this particular case you are only adding a column to a table you can try this approach and it will most likely work. If it doesn't then you have to implement your own migration with some SQL code.

The fast one:

Wherever you are creating your data base, add the following method: .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() . This will make that whenever your database version changes and a migration is needed and not provided it will just delete the old database and recreate it. Take into account that this solution will wipe out all the info you had saved up until that point, so try to use it only if you are in a rush and don't care to maintain the data between updates.